# How to delete a directory in Python 3.x with files in it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os 
shutil.rmtree('Path')
```

It does not delete it and gives me an error. I am using Python 3.7.4
The error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Muneeb Khurram\Desktop\gpa.py", line 2, in 
>       shutil.rmtree('C:/Users/Muneeb Khurram/Desktop/Py')
>   NameError: name 'shutil' is not defined

Comment: You need to `import shutil` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to `pip install shutil` into your computer. And `import shutil`, before you use `shutil.rmtree('Path')`.

Comment: You don’t need to pip install it’s a part of the python package